# How to configure partytown builder for GTM in angular?

Tags: angular, google-tag-manager, partytown

was trying to add `type="text/partytown"` after following the config steps [partytown](https://partytown.builder.io/angular)

```
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
          'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
          event: 'gtm.js'
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j = d.createElement(s),
          dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src =
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl + '&gtm_auth=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&gtm_preview=env-000&gtm_cookies_win=x';
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
      })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXXXX')
```

> var myDomain=google_tag_manager["GTM-xxxxxxx"].macro(3),site_links=document.getElementsByTagName("a"),target_links=google_tag_manager["GTM-xxxxxxx"].macro(4);Array.prototype.forEach.call(site_links,function(a){for(i=0;i<target_links.length;i++)0>a.href.indexOf(myDomain)&&a.href.includes(target_links[i])&&(a.href+="?_ga\x3d1628004784.1685101889")}); TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
> at WorkerBase.get (partytown-ww-sw.js?v=0.8.0:1143:33)
> at eval (eval at run (partytown-ww-sw.js?v=0.8.0:703:9), :3:260)
> at NodeList.forEach ()
> at Proxy.eval (eval at run (partytown-ww-sw.js?v=0.8.0:703:9), :3:194)
> at run (partytown-ww-sw.js?v=0.8.0:703:37)
> at runScriptContent (partytown-ww-sw.js?v=0.8.0:691:13)
> at partytown-ww-sw.js?v=0.8.0:1772:54
> at receiveMessageFromSandboxToWorker (partytown-ww-sw.js?v=0.8.0:1776:19)
> runScriptContent @ partytown-ww-sw.js?v=0.8.0:693
> (anonymous) @ partytown-ww-sw.js?v=0.8.0:1772
> receiveMessageFromSandboxToWorker @ partytown-ww-sw.js?v=0.8.0:1776